# Using a templated node struct pointer inside a non templated struct in C++

Tags: c++, list, templates, struct, stack

im working with stacks and lists in C++.

i have this templated node for the stack

```
template <typename TS>
    struct spNodoPila {
        TS info;
        spNodoPila<TS>* next;
    };
```

and i want to insert a pointer for it in another node struct for the list (that isnt templated), because i need that stack linked to list nodes:

```
struct spNodoLista {
        sInfoLista info;
        spNodoPila* cand;
        spNodoLista* prev;
        spNodoLista* next;
        spNodoVotos* vlink;
    };
```

the problem is that "spNodoPila* cand;" line gives me the error "argument list for template class is missing" and i cant figure why. would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The error message "argument list for template class is missing" tells you exactly what the error is.

```
template <typename TS>
    struct spNodoPila {
```

You declared this template. This template takes one parameter, one argument. It's called `TS`, here. To instantiate a template you must specify what the parameter is, what `TS` should be. For example, if you wish to have an instance of this template with an `int, you would write:

```
spNodePila<int> something;
```

Or maybe

```
spNodePila<int> *pointer;
```

But in your code you have:

```
    spNodoPila* cand;
```

You used the name of this template but failed to specify the template argument, its parameter. C++ does not work this way. To create an instance of a template you must always specify what the template parameters, or arguments are and that's exactly what the error message says.

It is unclear from your code example what your intent was here, but you need to figure out what template parameter you need to give here, and then specify it.